# Convert Block Document to String in Java with Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I have this code:

```
Block<Document> printBlock = document -> System.out.println(document.toJson().toString());

collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(new Document("Subscribers", new Document("$gte",  100))),
                Aggregates.match(new Document("Subscribers", new Document("$lte", 3900000))),
                //Aggregates.unwind("$T.SIEL.SIE"),
                Aggregates.sort(Sorts.ascending("Subscribers")),
                Aggregates.limit(5)))
        .forEach(printBlock);
```

And what i need is to obtain the result in text mode for later manipuling it with a variable.

I tried many things, but i cannot obtain it.

Comment: Please give an example of the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you add some context and explain what you are trying to accomplish? An example of the desired output, as requested by @Paul, could be useful.